# How to visualize patches with different values?

Tags: netlogo

I would like to visualize patches with different values of turtles' visits? For example, turning those patches into gradients colour in terms of visits. 1 visit could be light green, 5 visits could be green and 10 visits should be dark green. I am not sure if NetLogo Palette Extension would work in this case. Any thoughts? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think the Palette extension has been upgraded for NetLogo 5.x. The more recent [Gradient extension](https://github.com/NetLogo/Gradient-Extension/) offers the `gradient:scale` primitive, but in your particular case, as mentioned in the other answer, NetLogo's built-in [`scale-color`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#scale-color) should be enough:

```
patches-own [ visits ]    
to setup
  ask patches [
    set visits random 10
    set pcolor scale-color green visits 0 10
  ]
end
```

This will give you shades of "green" all the way from white to black. If you want to restrict colors from light green to dark green, you can give the primitive a slightly expanded range. Since the actual values you are mapping (i.e., your number of visits) will only fall in the middle of the range, you will never get extreme colors (i.e. white and black). In your case, that could be something like:

```
set pcolor scale-color green visits -5 15
```

Comment: Hi Nicolas, Thank you very much for your reply. Your answer is very detailed, and it really helps to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

NetLogo's `scale-color` command is just what you need:
http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#scale-color
(The docs include an example.)